# Validação de campos dinâmicos com Jquery.validate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Estou com dificuldade para validar os campos de uma tabela dinâmica utilizando o plugin *jquery.validate()* onde os `input` são sequenciais.

**JS**

```
$("#addLinha").on("click", function () { 
   // ADD QTD DE LINHAS INFORMADAS NO INPUP
   var n_prod = $("#n_prod").val(); 
   for ( var i = 0 ; i < n_prod ; i++ ) {
     contador++;
     var newRow = $("<tr>");
     var cols = "";

     cols += '<td class="contador" >' + contador + '</td>';
     cols += '<td><label text-align="center"><input class="produto" type="text" name="produto' + contador + '" /></label></td>';
     cols += '<td><label text-align="center"><input class="qtd spinner"     type="text" name="qtd' + contador + '"    onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this);"   /></label></td>';
     cols += '<td><label text-align="center"><input class="preco"   type="text" name="preco' + contador + '"  align="center" /></label></td>';
     cols += '<td class="col-md-2 total">R$ 0.00</td>';
     cols += '<td><a class="deleteLinha"> Excluir </a></td>';

     newRow.append(cols);

     $("#products-table").append(newRow);
  }
});
```

Tentei criar as regras de validação da seguinte forma, mas não funciounou como eu esperava:

```
$('#produto').validate({
   errorElement: 'div',
   errorClass: 'help-block',
   focusInvalid: true,
      rules: {
         for ( i = 1 ; i <= $('#hidden_linha').val() ; i++ ) {
            produto+i:{ required: true, maxlength: 100, minlength: 3 } 
         }
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pense em validar o formulário como um todo e tratar nas regras os elementos que você quer validar, assim você aplica o `.validate()` ao `<form>` e não diretamente ao elemento.

No seu caso que envolve a criação de `<input />` dinâmicamente lembre-se de que o *plugin* só conseguirá identificar os elementos a serem validados se eles já existirem, portanto chame o `$(form).validate();` após a criação dos elementos.

Outro fator importante é que você não precisa criar a mesma regra para cada `<input />`.

As `rules` por padrão identificam os elementos pela propriedade `name` mas o plugin te permite criar regras novas, onde você possa identificar e validar elementos de uma determinada classe por exemplo:

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules('produto', {
   required: true
});
```

[Documentação do plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) para futuras consultas.

**Respondendo ao comentário:**

Sim, é possível costumizar tanto a mensagem quanto sua estilazação:

```
//Crio um método com mensagem costumizada
$.validator.addMethod("prodRequired", $.validator.methods.required,"Produto é obrigatório");

//Abaixo defino como será as mensagens de erro.
$("#formulario").validate({
   errorPlacement: function(label, element) {
     label.addClass('arrow');
     label.insertAfter(element);
   },
   wrapper: 'span'
});
```

**Fontes:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247305/how-to-add-messages-to-a-class-with-addclassrules
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913677/jquery-validation-plugin-message-style

**Exemplo funcionando:**

```js
var contador = 0;

//Cria um método com mensagem.
$.validator.addMethod("prodRequired", $.validator.methods.required,
"Produto é obrigatório");

//Regra para a classe produto
jQuery.validator.addClassRules('produto', {
    prodRequired: true
});
    
$("#addLinha").on("click", function () { 
  // ADD QTD DE LINHAS INFORMADAS NO INPUP
  var n_prod = $("#n_prod").val(); 
  for ( var i = 0 ; i < n_prod ; i++ ) {
    contador ++;

    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";

    cols += '<td class="contador" >' + contador + '</td>';
    cols += '<td><label text-align="center"><input class="produto" type="text" name="produto' + contador + '" /></label></td>';
    cols += '<td><label text-align="center"><input class="qtd spinner"     type="text" name="qtd' + contador + '"    onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this);"   /></label></td>';
    cols += '<td><label text-align="center"><input class="preco"   type="text" name="preco' + contador + '"  align="center" /></label></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-md-2 total">R$ 0.00</td>';
    cols += '<td><a class="deleteLinha"> Excluir </a></td>';

    newRow.append(cols);

    $("#products-table").append(newRow);
  }

  //Abaixo defino como será as mensagens de erro.
  $("#formulario").validate({
    errorPlacement: function(label, element) {
          label.addClass('arrow');
          label.insertAfter(element);
      },
      wrapper: 'span'
  });
  
});
```

```css
span.arrow {
    margin-left: 6px;
    height:17px;
    background: url('http://i45.tinypic.com/f9ifz6.png') no-repeat left center;
}
label.error {
    height:17px;
    border-top:1px solid #99182c;
    border-right:1px solid #99182c;
    border-bottom:1px solid #99182c;
    margin-left:9px;
    padding:1px 5px 0px 5px;
    font-size:small;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>


<form id="formulario">
  <div>
    <input type="number" id="n_prod" name="n_prod" min="1" value="1" />
    <button type="button" id="addLinha">
      Adicionar Linha
    </button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <table id="products-table">
    </table>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" id="enviar" name="enviar">
      Enviar
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: muito bom amigo, não tenho tanto conhecimento nesta biblioteca ... mas venho utilizando a dois meses e me mostrou ser bem extensa e funcional !!! #Grato

Comment: funcionou legal, agora como seria possivel fazer referencia ao css dos erros para personalizar da maneira que quiser ??? E tambem configurar as respostas de 'messages' desta forma eu nao sei fazer e nao vi na API

Comment: Editei minha resposta e inclui alguns links de referências que podem te auxiliar.

Comment: cara, muito boomm !!! Obrigado, aprendi muito com esta solução sua e vou aproveitar para ver estas referencias.